# Como recorrer una tabla y extraer ciertos datos, con Selenium y python

Tags: python

Soy nuevo en python, en web scrapping y en selenium, asi que tengo un cumulo de todo a la vez.

He logrado acceder a la web, realizar un par de tareas basicas como algunos clicks y llegar a la pestaña que deseo llegar para extraer los datos, el detalle es que los datos estan en tablas y la direccion (XPATH) es la que muestro en el codigo de abajo. al ejecutar todo el codigo solo consigo que me devuelva el primer elemento una y otra vez.

Lo que en realidad necesito es : Que me devuelva todos los elementos que hay basicamente es cambiar el tr[1] por tr[2] y asi sucesivamente, pero no logro solucionarlo, ademas de ello, me gustaria hacer una comparacion por ejemplo en el precio_por_3_cartas si el precio es > 0.22 y booster_pack < 0.10, entonces que me lo extraiga. (No haria falta mostrar todos los elementos de la web, simplemente los que devuelven esta condicion).

```
paquetes = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('odd')

for paquete in paquetes:
    titulo = paquete.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/table/tbody/tr').text
    booster_pack = paquete.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[3]').text
    precio_por_3cartas = paquete.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[4]/span').text
    print(titulo,booster_pack,precio_por_3cartas)
```

Comment: podrías compartir la url ?

Comment: Si claro, disculpa lo tarde que respondi, [https://www.steamcardexchange.net/index.php?boosterprices] @LucasDamian

Comment: Cuando te refieres a todos los elementos, hablas de las 9mil entradas aprox ?

Comment: si y no, no hacen falta los 9mil, porque a partir del 500 seguramente no se cumpla la condicion de: precio_por_3cartas >0.22 y booster_pack <0.10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Voy a ofrecer una solución un poco rebuscada utilizando `pandas`, `selenium` y `BeautifulSoup`.

Lo primero que tenemos que hacer despues de hacer la solicitud a la url, es seleccionar el `dropdown`:

Como el elemento es `<option value="-1">All</option>` y se encuentra dentro de un `<select>`, se puede acceder por el atributo `value`, de la siguiente manera:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select

webelement = browser.find_element_by_tag_name('select')
select = Select(webelement)

# select by value 
select.select_by_value('-1')
```

**Para tener en cuenta:** En la página solo se encuentra **un** elemento con el tag `<select>`, por eso utilicé `.find_element_by_tag_name('select')`. De no ser así, puedes acceder a dicho elemento por ejemplo por `CSS_SELECTOR`, en este caso sería `browser.find_element_by_css_selector('#boosterpricelist_length > label > select')`

A partir de aquí ya tenemos lo que necesitamos, la tabla con todos elementos.

Ahora voy a guardar en una lista, los nombres que tienen las columnas, o sea el texto de los elementos `th`, utilizando una [list comprehension](https://realpython.com/list-comprehension-python/)

```
thead = browser.find_element_by_tag_name('thead')
columns = [th.text for th in thead.find_elements_by_tag_name('th')]
```

Ahora podemos aprovechar para utilizar `BeautifulSoup` ya que tenemos todo el texto plano en nuestro `browser`, para crear una lista de listas con todos los elementos de la tabla. Y lo haríamos de la siguiente manera:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(browser.page_source,'html.parser')

tbody = soup.find('tbody')
data = []
for td in tbody.find_all('tr'):
    
    row = [i.text for i in td.find_all('td')]
    
    data.append(row)
```

El código anterior define una lista vacia: `data`. y luego vamos a buscar todos los elementos `tr` de la tabla `tbody`. Iteramos sobre ellos y por cada vuelta del for, vamos a generar una lista con el contenido de cada `td` perteneciente a cada `tr` (row). Basicamente es:

```
-tbody
--tr
---td,td,td,td (contenido de cada td)
```

Entonces en `row` tenemos una lista, que vamos a ir agregandola a `data`. Al finalizar el loop, vamos a tener 9241 registros.

Todo muy lindo, pero ahora tenemos que limpiar los datos que obtuvimos, por eso vamos a utilizar `pandas` y crearemos un `dataframe` con lo que tenemos.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(data=data,columns=columns)
```

Ahora necesitamos limpiar la columna `Booster Pack`  y `Price for 3 Cards`. Vamos a modificar el tipo de dato para que sea de tipo `float`, para poder crear la condición solicitada. Para eso podemos utilizar [expresiones regulares](https://kanoki.org/2019/11/12/how-to-use-regex-in-pandas/).

En este caso tenemos esto `$0.84`   y vamos a pasarlo a `0.84`. Se puede hacer directamente `str.replace('$','')`, pero tenemos 9000 registros y no sabemos si realmente todos los registros tienen el mismo formato, cuando haces web scraping siempre te encuentras con "sopresas".

Entonces vamos a darle forma a las dos columnas:

```
df["Booster Pack"] = (df["Booster Pack"].str.extract(r"([\d,\.]+)", expand=False).astype(float))
```

`Price for 3 Cards` tiene `-24% ($0.68)` y queremos que sea `0.68`

```
df["Price for 3 Cards"] = (df["Price for 3 Cards"].str.split('$').str[1].str.extract(r"([\d,\.]+)", expand=False).astype(float))
```

Ahora solo nos falta crear la condición, y lo podemos hacer utilizando una *mascara booleana*.

```
condicion = (df['Price for 3 Cards'] > 0.22)&(df['Booster Pack'] < 0.10)
```

Y por último filtrar nuestro `dataframe` para ver cuales son los registros que cumplen dicha condición:

```
df[condicion]
```

y obtenemos:

```
    Game    Cards in Set    Booster Pack    Price for 3 Cards   Booster Creator Last Update
Combat Racers       8           0.08             0.67           +75% ($0.32)    76min ago
Duel VR             8           0.05             0.93           +84% ($0.32)    64min ago
Geek Resort         6           0.09             0.71           +79% ($0.43)    20min ago
Maze Roller         5           0.07             0.47           +86% ($0.52)    73min ago
Million to One Hero 5           0.04             1.10           +92% ($0.52)    84min ago
My Tribe            5           0.07             0.64           +86% ($0.52)    34min ago
Ossuary             5           0.03             0.66           +94% ($0.52)    163min ago
Riverbond           6           0.07             1.02           +84% ($0.43)    8min ago
```

Código completo:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

browser.get('https://www.steamcardexchange.net/index.php?boosterprices')




webelement = browser.find_element_by_tag_name('select')


select = Select(webelement)

# select by value 
select.select_by_value('-1')

thead = browser.find_element_by_tag_name('thead')
columns = [th.text for th in thead.find_elements_by_tag_name('th')]

soup = BeautifulSoup(browser.page_source,'html.parser')


tbody = soup.find('tbody')
data = []
for td in tbody.find_all('tr'):
    
    row = [i.text for i in td.find_all('td')]
    
    data.append(row)


df = pd.DataFrame(data=data,columns=columns)

df["Booster Pack"] = (df["Booster Pack"].str.extract(r"([\d,\.]+)", expand=False).astype(float))
df["Price for 3 Cards"] = (df["Price for 3 Cards"].str.split('$').str[1].str.extract(r"([\d,\.]+)", expand=False).astype(float))

condicion = (df['Price for 3 Cards'] > 0.22)&(df['Booster Pack'] < 0.10)

df[condicion]

browser.quit()
```

pd:Ten en cuenta que tu usas driver, solo tienes que cambiar browser por driver

Comment: WOW, creo que como novato, no podria haber llegado solo a la solucion XD,para probarla necesito instalar BeautifulSoup el cual lo he hecho con un pip install beautifulsoup4, ahora necesito pandas pero me recomiendan que instale Anaconda, es realmente esto necesario ? disculpa mis preguntas absurdas pero las necesito para poder probar el codigo xD

Comment: me olvide de importar la libreria pandas, ahora edito la respuesta asi tenes las librerias que utilicé. Anaconda es bueno para probar el codigo celda por celda en Jupyter Notebook, y a mi me ayudó mucho utilizar jupyter notebook

Comment: Ya he instalado ambas cosas, beautifulsoup4 y pandas, todo manual mediante cmd (tambien he instalado jupyter) hay alguna forma de poder contactarte y hablar contigo en privado ? lo digo por el tiempo de respuesta y para hacerte preguntas mas especificas (si no es molestia)

Comment: podes hablar en el chat, pero creo que necesitas una reputación mínima de 25.

Comment: claro y no llego al minimo... Podrias copiar todo el codigo en un pastebin ? no se si eso es contra las reglas de stackoverflow, porque al copiar el codigo desde aqui presento 3 errores,en la variable browser.

Comment: ahora lo agrego todo junto

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109756/discussion-between-anthonyeca-and-lucas-damian).

Answer (score 0):

pon la linea que contiene el error de esta manera

try:
variable = producto.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.pdp-link").text
except:
variable = None

de esta manera si no encuentra elemento lo salta y continua el programa te recomiendo aprender a manejar errores y excepciones en python